# Navigating to ViewController from AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, appdelegate

Is there a preferred method when, upon receiving a notification in `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`, I bring the user to a certain view controller*?

**For example**, if I have view controllers A, B, C, and D, a notification comes in, the app is running in the background with the user at screen A, B, or C, and I need to bring them to screen D, and back to their previous screen when they're done.

One method seems to be making A, B, C delegates of D, hooking them up with segues in storyboard, and doing performSegueWithIdentifier: in application:didReceiveLocalNotification:, but that doesn't scale well if I have ex. 60 screens.

Is there a better/best way to push a view controller on the screen from the AppDelegate and go back to wherever the user was previously when they're finished?

**Note this will not occur if the user is currently inside app, so as not to be disruptive.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally that kind of behavior is best achieved with modal view controllers.

However I wouldn't pop a modal view controller from the appDelegate but instead I'd make A, B and C subclasses of the same class. This class would have code to handle the notification by showing a modal view controller (with D) that when dismissed will show the view controller where you were when the notification came.

Though I don't understand your last sentence. If that's not going to happen when the user is inside the app why you bother to get him back to the previous screen?

Comment: Thank you sir, works great! Don't worry about the last sentence; meaningless.